# confused about gekko's deep learning interfaces

Tags: api, gekko

I am beginning to use gekko to train a model for tclab. I read the pages for [NN demo on keras and gekko](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DeepLearning) and [SISO model for tclab](http://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabA). Also the [API doc](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brain.html).

I found that the API doc for GEKKO is all about brain.brain and the demos are quite different. Which one should I follow or both is OK? I think brain.brain is quite clear and will give it a try.

Regards

Tibalt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Brain module](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brain.html) in Gekko because it simplifies the Deep Learning models. Here is an example in Gekko with the Brain module:

[image: Simple example]

```py
from gekko import brain
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)

b = brain.Brain()
b.input_layer(1)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.layer(tanh=2)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.output_layer(1)
# train
b.learn(x,y)      

# validate
xp = np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
yp = b.think(xp)  

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(xp,yp[0],'r-')
plt.show()
```

Here is that same example without the brain module in Gekko. You can see that writing out all of the network equations is quite tedious but it does give you additional flexibility to use any equation form or activation function.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,20)
y = np.sin(x)

# option for fitting function
select = True # True / False
if select:
    # Size with cosine function
    nin = 1  # inputs
    n1 = 1   # hidden layer 1 (linear)
    n2 = 1   # hidden layer 2 (nonlinear)
    n3 = 1   # hidden layer 3 (linear)
    nout = 1 # outputs
else:
    # Size with hyperbolic tangent function
    nin = 1  # inputs
    n1 = 2   # hidden layer 1 (linear)
    n2 = 2   # hidden layer 2 (nonlinear)
    n3 = 2   # hidden layer 3 (linear)
    nout = 1 # outputs

# Initialize gekko
train = GEKKO() 
test = GEKKO()

model = [train,test]

for m in model:
    # input(s)
    m.inpt = m.Param()

    # layer 1
    m.w1 = m.Array(m.FV, (nin,n1))
    m.l1 = [m.Intermediate(m.w1[0,i]*m.inpt) for i in range(n1)]

    # layer 2
    m.w2a = m.Array(m.FV, (n1,n2))
    m.w2b = m.Array(m.FV, (n1,n2))
    if select:
        m.l2 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.cos(m.w2a[j,i]+m.w2b[j,i]*m.l1[j]) \
                                for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)]
    else:
        m.l2 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.tanh(m.w2a[j,i]+m.w2b[j,i]*m.l1[j]) \
                                for j in range(n1)])) for i in range(n2)]

    # layer 3
    m.w3 = m.Array(m.FV, (n2,n3))
    m.l3 = [m.Intermediate(sum([m.w3[j,i]*m.l2[j] \
            for j in range(n2)])) for i in range(n3)]

    # output(s)
    m.outpt = m.CV()
    m.Equation(m.outpt==sum([m.l3[i] for i in range(n3)]))

    # flatten matrices
    m.w1 = m.w1.flatten()
    m.w2a = m.w2a.flatten()
    m.w2b = m.w2b.flatten()
    m.w3 = m.w3.flatten()

# Fit parameter weights
m = train
m.inpt.value=x
m.outpt.value=y
m.outpt.FSTATUS = 1
for i in range(len(m.w1)):
    m.w1[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w1[i].STATUS=1
    m.w1[i].MEAS=1.0
for i in range(len(m.w2a)):
    m.w2a[i].STATUS=1
    m.w2b[i].STATUS=1
    m.w2a[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w2b[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w2a[i].MEAS=1.0
    m.w2b[i].MEAS=0.5
for i in range(len(m.w3)):
    m.w3[i].FSTATUS=1
    m.w3[i].STATUS=1
    m.w3[i].MEAS=1.0
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)

# Test sample points
m = test
for i in range(len(m.w1)):
    m.w1[i].MEAS=train.w1[i].NEWVAL
    m.w1[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w1['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w1[i].MEAS))
for i in range(len(m.w2a)):
    m.w2a[i].MEAS=train.w2a[i].NEWVAL
    m.w2b[i].MEAS=train.w2b[i].NEWVAL
    m.w2a[i].FSTATUS = 1
    m.w2b[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w2a['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w2a[i].MEAS))
    print('w2b['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w2b[i].MEAS))
for i in range(len(m.w3)):
    m.w3[i].MEAS=train.w3[i].NEWVAL
    m.w3[i].FSTATUS = 1
    print('w3['+str(i)+']: '+str(m.w3[i].MEAS))
m.inpt.value=np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo',label='data')
plt.plot(test.inpt.value,test.outpt.value,'r-',label='predict')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.show()
```

Here is the same example in Scikit-Learn:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi)
xr = x.reshape(-1,1)
y = np.sin(x)

# train
nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(3), 
                  activation='tanh',\
                  solver='lbfgs',max_iter=2000)
model = nn.fit(xr,y)

# validate
xp = np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
xpr = xp.reshape(-1,1)
yp = nn.predict(xpr)
ypr = yp.reshape(-1,1)
r2 = nn.score(xpr,ypr)
print('R^2: ' + str(r2))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(xpr,ypr,'r-')
plt.show()
```

Finally, here is the same example in Keras / TensorFlow:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

#################################################################
### Generate Data ###############################################
#################################################################

# generate training data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,20)
y = np.sin(x)
# save training data to file
data = np.vstack((x,y)).T
np.savetxt('train_data.csv',data,header='x,y',comments='',delimiter=',')

# generate test data
x = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
# save test data to file
data = np.vstack((x,y)).T
np.savetxt('test_data.csv',data,header='x,y',comments='',delimiter=',')

#################################################################
### Scale data ##################################################
#################################################################

# load training and test data with pandas
train_df = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

# scale values to 0 to 1 for the ANN to work well
s = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

# scale training and test data
sc_train = s.fit_transform(train_df)
sc_test = s.transform(test_df)

# print scaling adjustments
print('Scalar multipliers')
print(s.scale_)
print('Scalar minimum')
print(s.min_)

# convert scaled values back to dataframe
sc_train_df = pd.DataFrame(sc_train, columns=train_df.columns.values)
sc_test_df = pd.DataFrame(sc_test, columns=test_df.columns.values)

# save scaled values to CSV files
sc_train_df.to_csv('train_scaled.csv', index=False)
sc_test_df.to_csv('test_scaled.csv', index=False)

#################################################################
### Train model #################################################
#################################################################

# create neural network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")

# load training data
train_df = pd.read_csv("train_scaled.csv")
X1 = train_df.drop('y', axis=1).values
Y1 = train_df[['y']].values

# train the model
model.fit(X1,Y1,epochs=5000,verbose=0,shuffle=True)

# Save the model to hard drive
#model.save('model.h5')

#################################################################
### Test model ##################################################
#################################################################

# Load the model from hard drive
#model.load('model.h5')

# load test data
test_df = pd.read_csv("test_scaled.csv")
X2 = test_df.drop('y', axis=1).values
Y2 = test_df[['y']].values

# test the model
mse = model.evaluate(X2,Y2, verbose=1)

print('Mean Squared Error: ', mse)

#################################################################
### Predictions Outside Training Region #########################
#################################################################

# generate prediction data
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
# scale input
X3 = x*s.scale_[0]+s.min_[0]
# predict
Y3P = model.predict(X3)
# unscale output
yp = (Y3P-s.min_[1])/s.scale_[1]

plt.figure()
plt.plot((X1-s.min_[0])/s.scale_[0], \
         (Y1-s.min_[1])/s.scale_[1], \
         'bo',label='train')
plt.plot(x,y,'r-',label='actual')
plt.plot(x,yp,'k--',label='predict')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('results.png')
plt.show()
```